# ERROR CardBoard Unity3D --> libc Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1) libvrunity.so

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

ERROR CardBoard

Show logo unity and crash...

Export unity3d to eclipse and debug in logcat...

> libc Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1) libvrunity.so

I know it is a memory allocation problem, but I want to know how is solved. Thank you.

CONTEXT:

CardBoard unitypackage v0.5
unity3D (4.6 and 5.02)
API 22 Android
win 8 64bits
LG-D805 (LG G2)